# Sort list of dictionaries by date in Python 3.4

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries like this but with many more dictionaries:

```
x = [{"duration":datetime.time(5,30),"date":datetime.date(2016,02,13)},{"duration":datetime.time(3,30),"date":datetime.date(2016,02,11)},{"duration":datetime.time(2,0),"date":datetime.date(2016,02,16)}]
```

Is there a way to sort this list in ascending order of `date` using Python keywords such as `sorted` and `lambda` without making a custom sorting function? I have been looking at the `sorted` [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#sorted) and the use of `lambda` in the optional `key` argument.

Comment: That's a list, not an array.

Comment: @AdamSmith Whoops, I'll edit that

Comment: @AdamSmith I have no idea how I didn't find the duplicate -_-

Comment: No worries! This is a well written, well answered question. Pointing it at the canonical question just creates more search terms that people can google to end up at the right answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While posting the question I figured out the answer so thought I should share.

```
x = sorted(x, key = lambda k: k["date"])
```

Comment: also acceptable is `x.sort(key=operator.itemgetter("date"))`

Comment: If your list is called x then you should change it into something like x = sorted(x, key = lambda k: k["date"])

Comment: @Hyperion updated, it does add to clarity.