# Sorting a list of dictionary values by date and time in python

Tags: python, sorting

I want to sort the following data by date and time.

```
{'TID': 'B1', 'sno': '2', 'datetime': '04-13-12 17:21:18:83'}
{'TID': 'A1', 'sno': '4', 'datetime': '11-17-12 22:50:59:30'}
{'TID': 'A2', 'sno': '3', 'datetime': '11-17-12 22:51:00:66'}
{'TID': 'B6', 'sno': '2', 'datetime': '10-28-12 07:26:02:19'}
{'TID': 'B0', 'sno': '8', 'datetime': '02-26-16 08:13:01:30'}
{'TID': 'B4', 'sno': '8', 'datetime': '02-26-16 08:13:02:43'}
{'TID': 'C1', 'sno': '9', 'datetime': '03-08-15 17:12:55:81'}
{'TID': 'A2', 'sno': '23', 'datetime': '03-08-15 17:31:31:12'}
```

Solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652291/sorting-a-list-of-dictionary-values-by-date-in-python) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35198937/sort-list-of-dictionaries-by-date-in-python-3-4) don't work for me.

Hee is my code:

```
mylist=[]
with open(path+outfile) as fid:
    for line in fid:
        mylist.append(eval(line))


from operator import itemgetter
newlist = sorted(mylist, key=itemgetter('datetime')) 
for item in newlist:
    print(str(item))
```

here is the output of the above code:

```
 {'sno': '8', 'TID': 'B0', 'datetime': '02-26-16 08:13:01:30'}
{'sno': '8', 'TID': 'B4', 'datetime': '02-26-16 08:13:02:43'}
{'sno': '9', 'TID': 'C1', 'datetime': '03-08-15 17:12:55:81'}
{'sno': '23', 'TID': 'A2', 'datetime': '03-08-15 17:31:31:12'}
{'sno': '2', 'TID': 'B1', 'datetime': '04-13-12 17:21:18:83'}
{'sno': '2', 'TID': 'B6', 'datetime': '10-28-12 07:26:02:19'}
{'sno': '4', 'TID': 'A1', 'datetime': '11-17-12 22:50:59:30'}
{'sno': '3', 'TID': 'A2', 'datetime': '11-17-12 22:51:00:66'}
```

If you notice, the above output is not sorted by date and time.

Comment: what is `83` in this notation `04-13-12 17:21:18:83` ?

Comment: If your `datetime` values were done properly, that other solution would work.

Comment: I don't see how it is _not_ sorted. It is sorted alphabetically. Problem is: you have months first, so you need to parse the date first.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre. I'm new to python. Can you help me to do that?

Comment: @chandresh You'd perhaps better just fix your data.

Comment: Actually, It is machine generated data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

alphanumerical sort doesn't work here because the date is month-day-year. For it to work properly it should be year-month-day. I defined an helper function to split the date elements and rebuild a `tuple` so natural tuple sort matches date sort:

```
def sortable_date(x):
    d,t = x['datetime'].split()
    dtoks = d.split('-')
    #        year     month    day     time
    return (dtoks[2],dtoks[0],dtoks[1],t)

result = sorted(data,key=sortable_date)
```

Another possibility would be to sort according to parsed date, like this:

```
result = sorted(data,key=lambda x : time.strptime(x['datetime'],"%m-%d-%y %H:%M:%S:%f"))
```

with your data I get:

```
{'TID': 'B1', 'datetime': '04-13-12 17:21:18:83', 'sno': '2'}
{'TID': 'B6', 'datetime': '10-28-12 07:26:02:19', 'sno': '2'}
{'TID': 'A1', 'datetime': '11-17-12 22:50:59:30', 'sno': '4'}
{'TID': 'A2', 'datetime': '11-17-12 22:51:00:66', 'sno': '3'}
{'TID': 'C1', 'datetime': '03-08-15 17:12:55:81', 'sno': '9'}
{'TID': 'A2', 'datetime': '03-08-15 17:31:31:12', 'sno': '23'}
{'TID': 'B0', 'datetime': '02-26-16 08:13:01:30', 'sno': '8'}
{'TID': 'B4', 'datetime': '02-26-16 08:13:02:43', 'sno': '8'}
```

Comment: I was relying on dateutil, but it failed me :D

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own key function to extract and parse the datetime:

```
import datetime
from operator import itemgetter

mylist = [{'TID': 'B1', 'sno': '2', 'datetime': '04-13-12 17:21:18:83'},
{'TID': 'A1', 'sno': '4', 'datetime': '11-17-12 22:50:59:30'},
{'TID': 'A2', 'sno': '3', 'datetime': '11-17-12 22:51:00:66'},
{'TID': 'B6', 'sno': '2', 'datetime': '10-28-12 07:26:02:19'},
{'TID': 'B0', 'sno': '8', 'datetime': '02-26-16 08:13:01:30'},
{'TID': 'B4', 'sno': '8', 'datetime': '02-26-16 08:13:02:43'},
{'TID': 'C1', 'sno': '9', 'datetime': '03-08-15 17:12:55:81'},
{'TID': 'A2', 'sno': '23', 'datetime': '03-08-15 17:31:31:12'}]

def key_function(item_dictionary):
    '''Extract datetime string from given dictionary, and return the parsed datetime object'''
    datetime_string = item_dictionary['datetime']
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(datetime_string, '%m-%d-%y %H:%M:%S:%f')

mylist.sort(key=key_function)
```

result:

```
[{'TID': 'B1', 'datetime': '04-13-12 17:21:18:83', 'sno': '2'},
 {'TID': 'B6', 'datetime': '10-28-12 07:26:02:19', 'sno': '2'},
 {'TID': 'A1', 'datetime': '11-17-12 22:50:59:30', 'sno': '4'},
 {'TID': 'A2', 'datetime': '11-17-12 22:51:00:66', 'sno': '3'},
 {'TID': 'C1', 'datetime': '03-08-15 17:12:55:81', 'sno': '9'},
 {'TID': 'A2', 'datetime': '03-08-15 17:31:31:12', 'sno': '23'},
 {'TID': 'B0', 'datetime': '02-26-16 08:13:01:30', 'sno': '8'},
 {'TID': 'B4', 'datetime': '02-26-16 08:13:02:43', 'sno': '8'}]
```